# How to convert timestamp in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, timestamp

So this is my data `November 30, 2021 at 12:00:00 PM UTC+7` how would it convert it into something like this `November 30, 2021`?

Answer (score 2):

according to your question,if your data is the all the format like  `November 30, 2021 at 12:00:00 PM UTC+7`, you can just split the data by blank or `at` symbol,why not do it simply

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using other libraries, the moment.js one is pretty well documented and thorough.

Comment: Moment.js have served the web very well, but it's an old piece of software and nowadays there are better alternatives if starting off on a new project. Even moment.js themselves think so. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/

I would recommend using day.js instead

Comment: moment(var.date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY [at] hh:mm:ss A ZZ').format('LL')
Do you know why it results in an invalid date?

Comment: @ShamPooSham how would I format November 30, 2021 at 12:00:00 PM UTC+7 this is what I've come up with but it doesn't work `dayjs(var.date, "MM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss A ZZ").format("LL")`

Comment: You should probably have `MMMM` instead of `MM`, and also escape `,`, `at` and `UTC`. So something like this: `dayjs(var.date, "MMMM[,] DD YYYY [at] hh:mm:ss A [UTC]ZZ")`. Not sure though

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short sample of what I recently used in my code, using **moment.js**

```
import moment from 'moment';

let convertedDate = moment(date)
return convertedDate.format("LLL") // this returns December 15, 2021 10:38 AM
```

Your case may be rather:

```
moment().format('LL');   // December 15, 2021
```

There are a lot of different format types, check them [here](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: `moment(var.date).format('LL')` I did this but it's not working for some reason it says Invalid Date

Comment: The moment() function requires a timestamp as an input - e.g 1399919500000. It should be the timestamp formatted as a number

Comment: `November 30, 2021 at 12:00:00 PM UTC+7` so how would I turn this into a timestamp formatted as a number?

Comment: Having this string, you should remove "at", so: 

`let correctTimeString  = "November 30, 2229 at 12:00:00 PM UTC+7".split("at").join("");`
and then 
`let time = Date.parse(correctTimeString)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `toLocaleDateString` function to easily convert any date into your desired output by passing options to it.

```js
const options = { year: "numeric", month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const options = { year: "numeric", month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

**strong text**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).